# C# : asp.net 3.5 : Deserialize JSON - how to get each object string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

i know there is other places that give this answer but what i am trying to achieve is more complicated,  this is my code for deserialization :

this is the json data for exemple :

```
data = @"{""ShiftID"":""2"",""EmpName"":""dsdsfs""}";

Dictionary<string, string> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(data);
List<string> list = new List<string>(values.Keys);
// Loop through list
foreach (string k in list)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("'{0}', '{1}'", k, values[k]);
}
```

this will return ShiftID,2 and EmpName, dsdsfs like you know but!

What happen if my json string look like this with multiple values :

```
data = @"{""ShiftID"":""2"",""EmpName"":""dsdsfs""},{""ShiftID"":""4"",""EmpName"":""dsdsfd""}";
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

> What happen if my json string look like this with multiple values
>
> `data = @"{""ShiftID"":""2"",""EmpName"":""dsdsfs""}, {""ShiftID"":""4"",""EmpName"":""dsdsfd""}";`

An error because this is not valid JSON. You probably meant:

```
data = @"[{""ShiftID"":""2"",""EmpName"":""dsdsfs""},{""ShiftID"":""4"",""EmpName"":""dsdsfd""}]";
```

Now you could deserialize into an array of dictionaries:

```
var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>[]>(data);
foreach (var element in values)
{
    foreach (var entry in element)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("'{0}', '{1}'",
            entry.Key,
            entry.Value
        );
    }
}
```

or even better, define a model to represent your entities:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string ShiftID { get; set; }
    public string EmpName { get; set; }
}
```

and now deserialize into a list of employees:

```
var employees = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee[]>(data);
foreach (var employee in employees)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("'{0}', '{1}'",
        employee.ShiftID,
        employee.EmpName
    );
    }
}
```

Comment: Well i get the values but not the columns? you got an idea

Comment: I need to get the value ShiftID and EmpName because it will always be something different

Comment: @user181248, I have fixed my first code. It should be `foreach (var entry in element)` instead of `foreach (string entry in element)`.

Comment: 500 error means that there is an exception somewhere happening in your ASP.NET application. Were you able to debug it?

Answer (score 0):

Thats invalid JSON. I think what you are looking for is a JSON array, which would enclose the entire string you have within brackets... [{"ShiftID": "2",...},{"ShiftId": "3",...}]